# How to remove form's NavigationService?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a frame with a few pages. The frame has its own journal:

```js
JournalOwnership="OwnsJournal"
```

When I pass 2 pages, I want to clean the frame `NavigationService`:

```js
Frame parent_frame = (Frame)Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("content_frame");

JournalEntry remove = parent_frame.RemoveBackEntry();

while (parent_frame.NavigationService.CanGoBack) {
    parent_frame.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    MessageBox.Show("Remove");
}
```

But after cleaning `NavigationService` I can go back.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that is to handle the frame Navigated event:

`frame.Navigated += frame_Navigated;`

```
void frame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    frame.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
}
```

Comment: But this.NavigationService.BackStack dont have Any

Comment: Then it must be a first page of your app. For reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394012%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: I create desctop app not for Windows Phone

Comment: If you never intend on going "back" to the previous entry, you can use NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() to clear out the history each time you navigate. The easiest way to do that is to handle the Frame's Navigated event. See updated answer,

Answer (score 0):

I've removed all possible pages in `NavigationService.BackStack` and added event when I remove the last page.

```js
Frame root = (Frame)Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("content_frame");
int i = 0;

while (root.NavigationService.CanGoBack) {
    i++;
    root.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
}
root.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
MessageBox.Show("Deleted - " + i);


NavigatedEventHandler navigated_handle = null;
navigated_handle = (o, e) => {
    ((Frame)o).RemoveBackEntry();
    MessageBox.Show("Do and remove itself!");
    root.Navigated -= navigated_handle;
};
root.Navigated += navigated_handle;
```